# Total running time calculation using Big-O Asymptotic analysis

Tags: c++, big-o, complexity-theory

```cpp
int f1(int n)
{ 
    int sum = 73; 
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    { 
        for (int j=i; j >= 5; j/2)
        {
            sum--;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calculating the Total Running time of this algorithm determining the cost of each statement.
I have got so far is this:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++) // runs in n time
for(int j=i; j >= 5; j/2) // runs in T(n/2) time
sum-- // runs nc/2 times (because it lies in inner loop which is running n/2 times)
```

**Now, I have to find T(n) but I am not getting whether to do this n*T(n/2)) or n+ T(n/2).
When T(n/2) solved by substitution it gives, O(log n) then would be the big-o for this algorithm O(n^2) or O(n log n)?**

Comment: Beware that `j/2` has no effect. You have an infinite loop if the inner loop is entered.

Comment: I am guessing `j/2` was a mistake and was intended to be `j = j/2` or `j /= 2`?

Comment: silly me! ... apparently I am not awake yet ...

Comment: What is the `T` notation? Does it stand for Theta (aka Big O)? The wording makes it seem distinct from Big O.

Comment: I am using T as the function name.

Comment: In your formulas, `*` indicates repetition and `+` indicates sequencing. Do you repeat something `n` times, or do you first do one thing and then another?

Comment: When outer loop executes, the inner loop executes j/2 times. It's like repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Big-O will be O(n*Log2(n))

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) // n
    for(int j = i; j >= 5; j /= 2) //log2(n) Because j is divided by 2 each step
        sum--; // 1
```